# VS2010, I miss webforms template and I can not add aspx files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

it is first toime it happens me in Visual Studio 2010. I was surprised when I go to add a file in Solution Explorer, Web Forms doesnt appear.

[image]

[image]

I don't know to add Webforms to my vs2010, I tried to execute the next comand in cmd.exe

[image]

I didn't get results and I am in the same situation.
.
How can I add WebForm in vs2010? Other thing I did was in online templates and no results neither

Answer (score 0):

It was something wrong of versión of Web Pages. Now it is working, I have ASP.Net v2 and it was created as v1.